# jquery ui tabs showing exception when selecting using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I've a simple UI tabs like this

```
<div id="tabs">             
<ul><li><a href="#tabs-1">Single</a></li><li><a href="#tabs-2">Matchmaker</a></li></ul></div>
```

later i use the jquery option to select a tab

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var role = 1; //some value, this value changes and i'm sure its has its value.
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", role);
    }
);
</script>
```

i've even tried `$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 0);`

but no luck.. what may be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var role = 1; //some value, this value changes and i'm sure its has its value.
        $("#tabs").tabs({ selected: role  });
    }
);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6rB2w/1/

EDIT - there was a problem with the markup: look at this fiddle that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/6rB2w/11/

```
<div id="tabs">             
<ul><li><a href="#tabs-1">Single</a></li><li><a href="#tabs-2">Matchmaker</a></li></ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis.</p>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var role = 1; //some value, this value changes and i'm sure its has its value.
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        alert('now change the selected tab');
        $("#tabs").tabs( "select", role );
    }
);
```

The problem is that the first div must wrap around the other two divs otherwise when you swtich tab with  `$("#tabs").tabs( "select", role );` it gives an error

Comment: I've a situation where i load the tabs initially with the following code `$(function() {$("#tabs").tabs();});` but after that i've a ajax request when i click any of these tabs and based on the output(i.e role in my code) i try to change the tab and selected automatically.. I think this causes the issue.. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is `.tabs('select', TAB-INDEX)` (tab index is zero-based).

Comment: i know its zero based, so if i give 1 the second tab should be selected. am i right?  by the way , is that property `select` or `selected`?